# Why echo Fails To Show The String Before print_r() Displays The Array Values?

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo, explode

I need to check for 3 banned words on a webpage. Check against the first 3 words only that are found on the page.

The page is:
tcm.DOTCOM/this-month/article/297159%7C0/Dirty-Harry.html

The 3 banned words are:
dirty harry
callahan
clint eastwood

I am writing the code in this format:

Found Word On Page (Serially):
Banned Word (Serially):

Now, the first 8 words on the page are the following from the string:
"make a taglib call to fetch the masterProfileImage".

make 
a 
taglib

So now, based on my code, I should get results like this:

word:make
No Match: dirty harry

word:a
No Match: callahan

word:taglib
No Match: clint eastwood

But I got result like the following instead, where the print_r value was shown first and then the echo. This is wrong way round.

No Match: dirty harry
word:make

No Match: callahan
word:a

No Match: clint eastwood

When I refreshed my Chrome a few times, I started seeing a blank page.
What is wrong ?

```
<?php

/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


// 1). $curl is going to be data type curl resource.
$curl = curl_init();

// 2). Set cURL options.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tcm.com/this-
month/article/297159%7C0/Dirty-Harry.html');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// 3). Run cURL (execute http request).
$result = curl_exec($curl);

// 4). Close cURL resource.
curl_close($curl);


//Set banned words.
$banned_words = array("dirty harry","callahan", "clint eastwood");
$content = $result;

//Separate each words found on the cURL fetched page.
$word = explode(" ", $content);
print_r ($word[0]); // 1st word
print_r ($word[1]); // 2nd word
print_r ($word[2]); // 3rd word

$i = 0;
foreach ($banned_words as $ban) {
    if (stripos($word[$i],$ban) > -1){
        echo "word:";
        print_r ($word[$i]);?><br><?php
        echo "Match: $ban<br>";
    }else{
        echo "word:";
        print_r ($word[$i]);?><br><?php
        echo "No Match: $ban<br>";  
    }
    $i++;
}


?>
```

Comment: It's kind of funny that you go crazy with the error handling, but fail to check for cURL errors, or if there is any kind of error in the cURL response.

Comment: There's all kinds of bugs and bad coding here. Some of the bigger problems are that you are not using RETURNTRANSFER with cURL, you are not actually looping through your `$word` array, and when you explode `$result` you then go on to check if strings still contain spaces. For instance "dirty harry" has a space in it, but you just exploded `$result` by " ", so there will never ever be an occurrence of "dirty harry". There can be no real answer here. Whatever you are doing, there is a better solution.

Comment: Go crazy with error handling ? How, where & when ?
How-about showing that solution ? And, thanks for pointing out my mistake regarding the space.

Comment: Because of the way Stack Overflow works, my fixes to your code cannot be deemed an appropriate answer, and I can't suggest that you don't downvote me, so posting what I did only sets me up for downvotes. I'll post it online somewhere and provide the link.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/skunkbad/158a4980a94ebb5798c6f1fd7f433089 Check it. I'm leaving for a bike ride, so can't respond, but you should be able to see some of your errors.

Comment: Brian Gottier,

Don't worry. I am not into DownVoting. Only UpVoting. Unless ofcourse, you use bad language.
Aslong as I get a working solution, I'm willing to UpVote, if I remember to do it. If I forget, then PM and remind me. I am not used to forums that much.

Comment: Brian Gottier, Had a quick glance at that link. Seems like you have solved my problem. But, I will thoroughly check the code tomorrow. Tonight short on time. Thank you for your time & effort!

Now, how do I UpVote your reply ?

Comment: I supplied an answer with a little more explaining.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I took the code that I showed you in that gist, and I made some more comments for you, so that you would see what I thought you were doing wrong. That doesn't mean I'd do this, or even know what you're doing, but there's a lot to think about, so make sure to look at the comments I put in this code:

```
<?php

/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/

/**
 * You can declare strict_types if you want,
 * but why? Why make life harder? Especially if
 * you're a beginner, just forget about it.
 */
//declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Enabling error reporting and displaying errors is
 * a good thing. MySQL will normally output errors, so
 * how much you need that line is debatable.
 */
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


// 1). $curl is going to be data type curl resource.
$curl = curl_init();

// 2). Set cURL options.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tcm.com/this-month/article/297159|0/Dirty-Harry.html');

/**
 * You probably don't need this at all, because you are not connecting to HTTPS
 */
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/**
 * You had not set RETURNTRANFER, so instead of the content
 * being applied to a variable, it would just be output
 * to the browser.
 */
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// 3). Run cURL (execute http request).
$result = curl_exec($curl);

/**
 * It is possible for cURL to return a response that
 * is not a good response. You can't count on the response
 * being usable, so you need to do a little error handling.
 * What I've provided here is the most basic way to see
 * if the response is good.
 */
$response = curl_getinfo( $curl );
if( $response['http_code'] == '200' )
{
    //Set banned words.
    /**
     * See how your words have spaces in them?
     */
    $banned_words = array("Dirty Harry","Callahan", "Clint Eastwood");

    //Separate each words found on the cURL fetched page.
    /**
     * Now you are exploding by space character, which means your
     * $word array will have elements that NEVER have space characters in them
     */
    $word = explode(" ", $result);

   //var_dump($word);

    /**
     * In your code, you had $i, and you had $i++
     * but you never looped through the $word array
     */
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($word); $i++){
        foreach ($banned_words as $ban) {
            if (stripos($word[$i],$ban) !== FALSE){
                echo "word: $word[$i]<br />";
                echo "Match: $ban<br>";
            }else{
                echo "word: $word[$i]<br />";
                echo "No Match: $ban<br>";  
            }
        }
    }
}

// 4). Close cURL resource.
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gottlier.
I have noted your latest code edit and will play with it tomorrow and experiment. If it works, I'll close this thread as resolved.
I have given you an UpVote for now.
Once again thank you for your volunteering (time & effort).
In the meanwhile, before I go to sleep, I will open a few more threads with my questions.